# I want to hide products with price is € 0,00

Tags: woocommerce, hide, product, zero, price

Hi to everyone: I want to hide products with price is € 0,00. I tried it with this code:

```
enter code hereadd_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'themelocation_product_query' );
function themelocation_product_query( $q ){
$meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
$meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => '_price',
            'value'     => 0,
            'compare'   => '>'
        );
$q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

If I enter 0, the product with the code above has disappeared. But how do I hide a product that have 0,00? I've tried all the code changes, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Thank you very much. Gisela

Comment: Now I could find the solution myself. But I still need a code for variable products that have a price of 0,00. Can someone please help me there?

Comment: The p class at the variations is "price variation_modified", but but I can't find the right solution.